# How to change meta tags with "ob" function

Tags: php, regex, tags, meta

I would like to change the meta tags with ob_ function. Every sigle page i have $headline $image and $description. But my code is not working I dont know why? I would be inportant because i copy-paste my site link to the facebokk I would like to see the single page things (image,headline, description).

Before the  I have the following code

```
       <?php 
        function fbtitle($fbtitle) {
            return (ereg_replace("<!--TITLE-->", $headline, $fbtitle));
        }

        function fbimg($fbimg) {
            return (ereg_replace("<!--IMG-->", "$image", $fbimg));
        }

        function fbdescription($fbdescription) {
            return (ereg_replace("<!--DESCRIPTION-->", "$description", $fbdescription));
        }

        ob_start("fbtitle");
        ob_start("fbimg");
        ob_start("fbdescription");
?>
```

My meta tags are:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<!--TITLE-->" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<!--IMG-->" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<!--DESCRIPTION-->" />
```

My content has:

```
$headline
$image
$description
```

At the end of the page I have

```
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: FYI: `ereg_*` functions are deprecated, use `preg_*` functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following [Buffer more information with PHP buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714815/buffer-more-information-with-php-buffer/29714850#29714850)
And it solved my problem

```
<?
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); 
ob_end_clean (); 
echo str_replace ('<!--DESCRIPTION-->', $pageDesc, $pageContents);
echo str_replace ('<!--IMG-->', $pageImg, $pageContents);
echo str_replace ('<!--URL-->', $pageUrl, $pageContents);
echo str_replace ('<!--TITLE-->', $pageTitle, $pageContents);
?>
```